# Adverb in a prepositional phrase and what it modifies

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases, modifiers

> I am with arguably the best basketball player in the nation.

Would this sentence above be correct, and if so, what does “arguably” modify?

Comment: What do _you_ think?

Comment: Compare your example with the *hopefully* in *Hopefully, he'll arrive in time for the funeral.* What does it modify? Hint: it doesn't mean he'll have a smile and a bounce in his step when he arrives.

Answer (score 1):

It's a modal (judgement-indicating) modifier and is best seen operating in the expanded paraphrase (OP justifies a male player):

- "*I am with the man who is the best basketball player in the nation.* (The statement [this man is the best basketball player in the nation] is *open to opinion*.)"

So it's qualifying the whole statement [this man is the best basketball player in the nation], hedging it, conceding that not all hold this opinion.

One can see why sentence-modifying (even recoverable-sentence-modifying) usages are preferred.

- "He is merely a youth." =

"He is one of that class of callow, naive, immature, rough-edged fairly hapless humans between the ages of x and y." Here, 'merely' comments (in a broad-brush way, of course) on the whole containing set.

Comment: This must be right.  Those of us who were brought up with rules like "adjectives qualify nouns and adverbs modify verbs" have had to get used to the idea that it is not (and never was) that simple.  They can modify whole verb phrases  or even whole sentences.  Yet are they not often are more relevant to some elements than others?  So in this example, the key elements (the point, if you will) is that this basketball player is probably "the best <of all basketball players> in the nation".  We are asked to take for granted that he is a basketball player in the USA, unless the author is an idiot.

Comment: I still hold out against the lumping of adjective-modifiers (_wide_ awake), adverb-modifiers (_very_ quickly), limiting etc modifiers (he _even_ eats mice) and modifiers-of-clauses (pragmatic markers of all ilks, traditionally classed as 'sentence adverbs', 'comment clauses' etc) together with adverbs (traditionally prototypical adverbs).

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs can modify verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs.

There are no other adverbs in the sentence, so that's ruled out.

The only real possibilities are the verb phrase "am with", and the adjective "best". The term "arguably" means that something may not be objectively true, but you're expressing a common opinion that it's true.

In this case, it's not likely to refer to  "am with" -- it's usually obvious whether you're with someone or not.

So that leaves "best". This is often a subjective opinion (it may be backed up with statistics, but it's rare that all the statistics point to the same best item, so we need to judge which are more significant). So it makes sense to qualify "best" with "arguably". Thus, the sentence essentially means

> I am with the person who many would consider the best basketball player in the nation.

Answer (score 0):

One way of figuring it out is to "divide and conquer", that is, to take a smaller part of the sentence (a *constituent part*) that still contains the word in question, because this will rule out some of the words that definitely aren't modified by it.

For example, with your sentence, i could do it like this:

> I am with [**arguably** the best basketball player in the nation].

because the entire phrase in square brackets can be replaced by a single pronoun, "him":

> I am with [him]

This rules out the verb "am".

Now you can do the same trick again inside this constituent part (which seems to be a noun phrase, because it can be replaced with a pronoun, and it takes place of an object of a preposition "with" in the original sentence):

> **arguably** the best basketball player in the nation

If it isn't obvious to you yet that it must modify the adjective "best" (which in turns modifies the noun "player"), try slicing it further. Sometimes it may give you ideas when you remove some constituent part, to see which other constituent will "feel lonely" (underdescribed) without it. E.g. what would happen if you remove the prepositional phrase "in the nation"? Who will feel lonely? When you figure that out, try replacing it, along with the word that it modifies, with another pronoun.

Try simplifying the phrase without changing its core meaning, because in simpler phrases it will be easier to see which word does the adverb (or other phrase) modify. E.g. a simpler phrase that still works the same is this:

> **arguably** the best dad in the nation

or even this:

> **arguably** the best dad

and this:

> **arguably** the best

(as in "He is arguably the best")